# Servicestack server sent events

Tags: servicestack

I just started messing with my own implementation of ServiceStack server events.

After reading the wiki section and reading the code of the chat application, I started creating my own new `mvc4` project and installing all the ServiceStack libraries via nuGet.

After configuring and creating the `AppHost`, I created a new "helloworld" service and started the site, just to make sure it worked (it worked indeed).

Now the main issues. Based on the existing example code (the chat application), I created the new HTML page and the service which calls `ServerEvents.NotifyChannel` and then I started the new site.

When calling the service via ajax (post) the debugger hits the break point, but the client events aren't fired when the service returns. Even more, it seems that the notify is sort of "cached/delayed" and when calling the service the second time, the client receives the data from the first call.

Should I use `servicestack.razor` views? Should I create another MVC application and again, build everything from scratch to test it?

editing this post to add code (as pointed out): https://github.com/xspadax/SS_SSE_Test

Comment: Please provide the server and client code used so we can see and be able to reproduce what the issue is.

Comment: Adding a link to a dump of your app doesn't tell us the issue your having, i.e. what service are you calling? what args are you calling it with? what outcome do you expect? I've tried your app, saw you have a new `echo` global handler and it gets called as expected when sending with a `cmd.echo` selector. It's not clear what other issues you're experiencing, please add step-by-step details on what you're trying and what's not working, include code snippets from your app when need be.

Comment: The main thing is that the event handlers on the index.cshtml are delayed.Let me clarify the step I follow to replicate the issue: starting the solution, I call the echo service with localhost/api/echo/firstString. The echo handler on the client side does nothing, then, when i call for the second time the echo service with localhost/api/echo/secondString, the echo event handler on the client side writes on the console "echo firstString" and so on, while I expect that when I call the echo service the client echo event handler responds with the right string...hope I explained it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is due to `Flush()` not working properly in **ASP.NET MVC** projects which seems to automatically buffer when compression is enabled, it can be disabled for dynamic pages with:

```
<system.webServer>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Incidentally not even the explicit API for Buffering output seems to have any effect when compression is enabled:

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Normal ASP.NET projects that don't use ASP.NET MVC like [ServiceStack + Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net/) doesn't have this issue.

#### Alternative code-only solution

[New API's were added](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/786ff8d055870a559f0c8a094c67ef02a5bab778) in **v4.0.32+** that's [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) to provide more custom hooks into ServiceStack's Server Events Feature, `OnInit` can be used to modify the HTTP Headers of the Server Events Stream, whilst the `OnPublish()` callback is fired after every message is published:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature { 
    /*
    OnInit = req => { //fired when sending headers in server event stream
        var res = (HttpResponseBase)req.Response.OriginalResponse; //Get MVC Response
        res.BufferOutput = false; // Should make Flush() work, but doesn't
    },
    */
    OnPublish = (res, msg) => { //fired after ever message is published
        res.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        res.Flush();    
    }
});
```

The solution above involves writing a number of trailing `\n` lines to **force a flush** in MVC. It's a valid alternative solution as trailing new lines are ignored in Server Sent Events.

Comment: Freaking awesome. It works as intended now. Thx a lot :)

Comment: I've had issues with the `ServiceStack.ServerEventsClient` using the `res.Write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");` approach.  I bashed my head on it for a while, and endued up using the `urlCompression` web.config setting for the time being.

Comment: I'm getting "System.InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed after the response has been submitted" when I add the OnPublish handler as above.  I know this post is a bit old... Is it still needed?  Is there a better way to handle this?  Heartbeats aren't making it to Chrome (though somehow they make it to Firefox).